# Is it possible to provide a different default executor in CompletableFuture#supplyAsync?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, trace, completable-future

I am currently adding distributed tracing to a project. However, trace spans use thread-local variables to store the trace context, e.g. `traceId` or `spanId`. Therefore, whenever you create a `CompletableFuture` you need to wrap its executor with a "traceable" executor which passes these variables to the new thread.

Spring Boot provides such [wrappers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#executor-executorservice-and-scheduledexecutorservice).

The proposal in the link above, is the following:

```java
CompletableFuture<Long> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    // perform some logic
    return 1_000_000L;
}, new TraceableExecutorService(beanFactory, executorService,
        // 'calculateTax' explicitly names the span - this param is optional
        "calculateTax"));
```

I want to avoid having to create a new `TraceableExecutorService` for every `CompletableFuture` I create. Main reasons are 1) this creates lots of code duplication, 2) I need to inject the `BeanFactory` everywhere, and 3) if someone forgets to add the wrapper, tracing breaks.

I have found three solutions so far, but they are not ideal:

1. Use this [context propagation](https://github.com/talsma-ict/context-propagation) library. While this might work (I tested this library a few months ago and cannot remember if I managed to make it work), it still suffers from #3 from above. You need to remember to import `nl.talsmasoftware.context.futures.ContextAwareCompletableFuture` instead of the typical java `CompletableFuture`, otherwise tracing won't working.
2. Create a small wrapper. This has the same problem. If you forget to use the wrapper, tracing stops working.
3. Add a static code analysis tool to the project which would check that you haven't used the typical java `CompletableFuture#supplyAsync`.

The wrapper I made looks like this:

```java
@Service
public class TraceAwareCompletableFutureFactory implements CompletableFutureFactory {

  private final BeanFactory beanFactory;
  private final Executor defaultExecutor;

  public TraceAwareCompletableFutureFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
    this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    this.defaultExecutor = wrap(ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
  }

  @Override
  public <T> CompletableFuture<T> supplyAsync(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    return supplyAsync(supplier, defaultExecutor);
  }

  @Override
  public <T> CompletableFuture<T> supplyAsync(Supplier<T> supplier, Executor executor) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier, wrap(executor));
  }

  private Executor wrap(Executor executor) {
    return new LazyTraceExecutor(beanFactory, executor);
  }
}
```

I have been thinking that a solution which might solve all three problems, would be to somehow make the default `CompletableFuture#supplyAsync` use a different default executor out of the box. Looking at the `CompletableFuture`'s code, this is not possible. `supplyAsync` is a static method and gets its default `Executor` from a `private static` variable.

Is there a way to do something like this? Can you maybe propose an alternative to my solutions?

Comment: So Spring suggests to create a new executor for each instance of `CompletableFuture`? If you use them a lot, this will kill your application fast.

Comment: I guess you can reuse the same, it's just an example ‍♂️

Comment: sorry, I should have made this more clear... we use a different tracing strategy and just like you have hit this same problem. We gave up on static analysis or weird things like this because `CompletableFuture` is one case, then there are pools that anyone can create, then there are individual threads that can be created, then there are libraries that might spawn a different thread...